# Keeping one interop office application alive (until IIS restart) for all users in ASP.NET WebForms Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, office-interop

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms web application using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to convert RDF/DOC/TXT into PDF files. I want to keep one instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` open throughout the lifetime of the application (until IIS Restart). Reason being that initialising initialising `Application` is resource intensive. Trying to convert a document with the assembly has a long turnaround (4-5+ seconds) time even for small documents and most of this is in `Application.Start()` and `Application.Quit()`. I'm hoping that by persisting the application itself, I will be able to increase document conversion throughput for my users.

Is this the right way to go about it? Is the best way to achieve this to store the `Application` as a `static` property of my non-static class? Am I going about this the right way?

```
//@see: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/592957/Converting-Document-Word-Excel

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public class DocManager
{
    //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    private static Application msWordDoc = null;

    // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value 
    private static object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    private Document doc = null;

    public DocManager()
    {
        if (msWordDoc == null)
        {
            //1 instance to be available to all users across multiple requests
            msWordDoc = new Application
            {
                Visible = false,
                ScreenUpdating = false
            };
        }
    }   
}
```

When the .NET application is stopped/restarted I want to ensure that the Word interop application is closed and released properly - even if my app crashes. Where do I need to insert the code for this? There is an example in [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/592957/Converting-Document-Word-Excel) like so:

```
try
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(msWordDoc);
    msWordDoc = null;
}

catch (Exception exReleaseObject)
{
    msWordDoc = null;
    //   Console.WriteLine(CMSResourceFile.REALESE_FAILED+ exReleaseObject);

}
finally
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Comment: You should **not** interop Office in server-side scenarios. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office There are other great 3rd party libraries that do work server-side.

Comment: @Wiktor Oh dear! I've tried `SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis` but have moved to interop as SautinSoft does not correctly convert all of the RTF data we have. It seems some of the RTF content we have only renders correctly in Word 2010 - incorrectly in all other versions of Word and Wordpad. When I try to process this content with SautinSoft, it returns `null` (i.e. conversion failed). Using Word 2010 + Interop it converts correctly. Are there other 3rd party libraries you recommend that have capability to specify document compatibility mode e.g. Word 2010?

Comment: Did it ever occur to you that specific RTF only renders properly in Word2010 and not other MS products is a sign that you should figure out what features that particular RTF is using that are likely non-standard and convert it to conformant RTF?

Comment: @Adam: try Aspose.

Comment: The static variable is fine. I wouldn't bother with the ReleaseComObject code, if the only reason you have Word on your machine is to do the conversion, i would rather just kill office whenever i suspect something might have gone wrong, restart it, and try again. Though I have to say this is very bad practice :)

Comment: @TnTinMn yYes of course, but I have inherited a legacy 300GB document database full of RTF content generated from some 500+ RTF document templates - fixing the content itself is out of scope. Having tried 6-8 RTF to PDF conversion tools I've settled with GleamTech DocumentUltimate. Does the job perfectly and ships with a nice DocumentViewer control and support for 70 document formats :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure that a Word process is finished correctly you need to release all underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article. You may also find the [When to release COM objects in Office add-ins developed in .NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/) article helpful.

Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

As a workaround you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you deal with open XML documents only. Or consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice around using this solution in production. We've abandoned this solution in favour of DocumentUltimate by GleamTech.

Comment: @Eugene in case of calling office applicaction from a server-side solution, like ASP.NET MVC, do you know which server-side account is used to run that office application? I have an ASP.NET app runnig on a web server that uses word interop SaveAS command  to convert a docx into a pdf and I need to know which server-side account is used. I have set custom identity for application pool and configured word dcom identity to run as "the interactive user".